# when the pattern consists of one character - my method does not work correctly, but when I pattern consists of two characters - IndexError

Tags: python

I wrote a method in which I look for all pattern matches in a string.

```
def patternSearchResultShow(text, pattern, counter, positions):
    print('Text = \'' + text + '\'')
    print('Pattern = \'' + pattern + '\'')
    print('Number of pattern occurrences: ' + str(counter))
    print('The template enters into positions: ' + str(positions))
    
def patternSearch(text, pattern):
    counter = 0
    positions = []
    for i in range(len(text) - 1):
        for j in range(len(pattern)):
            if (text[i + j] != pattern[j]):
                break
        if (j == len(pattern) - 1):
            positions.append(i)
            counter = counter + 1
            
    patternSearchResultShow(text, pattern, counter, positions)

print('My pattern search:')
text = 'aaaa'
pattern = 'a'
patternSearch(text, pattern)
```

First test:
`text` = 'aaaa'
`pattern` = 'a'
My output:

```
Number of pattern occurrences: 3
The template enters into positions: [0, 1, 2]
```

Expected output:

```
Number of pattern occurrences: 4
The template enters into positions: [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Ok, to get the above expected result, I changed the following line of code:
`for i in range(len(text) - 1):` -> `for i in range(len(text)):`
Now I have output:

```
Number of pattern occurrences: 4
The template enters into positions: [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Second test:
`text` = 'aaaa'
`pattern` = 'aa'
My output:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: `text[i + j]` will try to access outside the string when you get near the end of `text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing outside `text` when `i+j` gets too large, that causes the `IndexError`.

The reason why you're not finding all the matches is because you limit the range to `len(text)-1`, so you don't test the last character.

You should make the limit of the outer loop depend on the length of `pattern`

```
for i in range(len(text)-len(pattern)+1):
```

You can also replace the inner loop with a slice comparison.

```
if text[i:i+len(pattern)] == pattern:
    positions.append(i)
    counter += 1
```

Comment: what means ...i:i....? it is range of symbols? for example text = 'abcd', then text[1:3] = 'bc'?

Comment: Yes. This is Python's slice notation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation